# Errorapp:transformClassesWithDexForDebug ProcessException ExecException finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In android When I run the projcet ,i can met the error ,even if I created a new project on Android Studio ,the error still exist.I try the blog method but dont resolve it .

```html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

```html
 dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

this is code of my build.gradle file

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.damonzs.hz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
            jumboMode = true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem resides on the `buildToolsVersion` thata are you using to generate APK. Your are using version `24.0.0`, this is for compile SDK version 24, use a previous version instead.

For example:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

**"buildToolVersion" 24.0.0** use Java 1.8, and you are using Java 1.7 instead in this project. This build tool should be used in conjunction with **compileSdkVersion 24**.

Here is [SDK Build Tools Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html).

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.damonzs.hz"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
            jumboMode = true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
}
```